# Mongoose update array field with another value in the array

Tags: mongoose

Consider we have documents like below:

```
{
   "_id" : 1,
   "books" : [
      { "a" : 80, "b" : 75 },
      { "a" : 85, "b" : 100 },
      { "a" : 85, "b" : 100 }
   ]
}
{
   "_id" : 2,
   "books" : [
      { "a" : 90, "b" : 95 },
      { "a" : 95, "b" : 200 },
      { "a" : 85, "b" : 200 }
   ]
}
```

I want a query to replace all "a" values with the value of "b" for each element in books array.

I tried this query:

```
db.test.updateMany({}, {$set: {"books.$[].a": "$books.$.b"}}, {multi: true, upsert: true})
```

But it is setting the literal string of `$books.$.b` for all "a" values instead of the value of "b".
Can you tell me What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can try [update with aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/) starting rom MongoDB 4.2,

- `$map` to iterate loop of `books` array and inside in change update the value `a` and merge objects with current object using `$mergeObjects`

```
db.test.updateMany({},
  [{
    $set: {
      books: {
        $map: {
          input: "$books",
          in: {
            $mergeObjects: ["$$this", { a: "$$this.b" }]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }]
)
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/jqr1FShQ2Hv)

> Make sure your mongo shell version is greater than 4.2

Comment: This is giving error to me. I made the second argument object instead of array and the error is gone but the result is empty books array.

Comment: can you show Which error are you getting? this is supporting from mongodb 4.2 and also robo mongo will not support this because of old version of mongo shell.